# when applied tree layout in joint.js node graph ,Edges sticks and does not move properly

Tags: javascript, jointjs

**I am trying to draw graph in joint.js with tree layout , without any layout it works fine and edges responses properly ,but when changed to tree layout edges does not move with node in proper way if anyone knows how to workaround with edges in joint.js please response**

```js
 

      var namespace = joint.shapes;
      var graph = new joint.dia.Graph({}, { cellNamespace: namespace });
              var graphLayout = new joint.layout.TreeLayout({
                  graph: graph,
                  parentGap: 30,
                  siblingGap: 40
              });
              var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
                  el: document.getElementById('myholder'),
                  model: graph,
                  width: 600,
                  height: 1000,
                  gridSize: 10,
                  drawGrid: true,
                  background: {
                      color: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)'
                  },
                  cellViewNamespace: namespace
              });
              var rect = new joint.shapes.standard.Rectangle();
              rect.position(100, 30);
              rect.resize(100, 40);
              rect.attr({
                  body: {
                      fill: 'blue'
                  },
                  label: {
                      text: 'Hello',
                      fill: 'white'
                  }
              });
              rect.addTo(graph);
              var rect2 = rect.clone();
              rect2.translate(0, 300);
              rect2.attr('label/text', 'World!');
              rect2.addTo(graph);
              var link = new joint.shapes.standard.Link(
                  {
                      router: {
                          name: "manhattan",
                      },
                      connector: {
                          name: "rounded",
                      },
                      attrs: {
                          line: {
                              stroke: "#25085b",
                          },
                      }
              });
              link.source(rect);
              link.target(rect2);
              link.addTo(graph);
              var root = graph.getElements()[0].position(100, 100);
              graphLayout.layout();
```

```html
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.4.1/backbone.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jointjs/3.6.5/joint.js"></script>
        <script src="https://resources.jointjs.com/demos/rappid/build/package/rappid.js"></script>
           <div id="myholder" style="width: 100%"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the unusual curve / loop between the two nodes, you can change the `router` setting to `metro`, and that will resolve the issue.

So, instead of this:

```
router: {
    name: "manhattan",
},
```

do this

```
router: {
    name: "metro",
},
```

```js
var namespace = joint.shapes;
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph({}, { cellNamespace: namespace });
var graphLayout = new joint.layout.TreeLayout({
    graph: graph,
    parentGap: 30,
    siblingGap: 40
});
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: document.getElementById('myholder'),
    model: graph,
    width: 600,
    height: 1000,
    gridSize: 10,
    drawGrid: true,
    background: {
        color: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)'
    },
    cellViewNamespace: namespace
});

var rect = new joint.shapes.standard.Rectangle();
rect.position(100, 30);
rect.resize(100, 40);
rect.attr({
    body: {
        fill: 'blue'
    },
    label: {
        text: 'Hello',
        fill: 'white'
    }
});
rect.addTo(graph);

var rect2 = rect.clone();
rect2.translate(0, 300);
rect2.attr('label/text', 'World!');
rect2.addTo(graph);

var link = new joint.shapes.standard.Link(
    {
      router: { name: 'metro' },
      connector: { name: 'rounded' },
      attrs: {
          line: {
              stroke: '#333333',
              strokeWidth: 3
          }
      }
});
link.source(rect);
link.target(rect2);
link.addTo(graph);

var root = graph.getElements()[0].position(100, 100);
graphLayout.layout();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jointjs/3.6.5/joint.core.min.css" integrity="sha512-BSPFEtqveOD7IH9Oka9zaaMZqy9CUW0iBgag5tZozZYfFvWH5TuVCpdie9TpZ4UEYLkkOTnq6VmppA89CgVxYg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.4.1/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jointjs/3.6.5/joint.js"></script>
<script src="https://resources.jointjs.com/demos/rappid/build/package/rappid.js"></script>
<div id="myholder" style="width: 100%"></div>
```

Comment: I already tried it , doesn't work. can you please check this with three node?
When i change the position of node, link is still not moving after certain point

Comment: Just so I'm sure I understand the problem you're having - are you referring to [this unusual breaking](https://i.imgur.com/PW80TgL.png) of connectors / links?  If so, the same thing is happening with the [official example](https://i.imgur.com/bXXE4zQ.png) for the Tree layout. Perhaps using [Force directed](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v3.3/layout.html) would be a better choice for you?